# Use of the Internal Field Separator when capturing array data from a command in a bash script

Tags: shell, unix, ifs

When I run the command

```
git cherry origin/Server_Dev
```

in my git repository, I get a list of commits of the form

```
+ 95b117c39869a810595f1e169c64e728d2d7443d
+ e126f1b996ecf1d2a8cf744c74daa92cce338123
+ 869169a6cb0bbe8f1922838798580a1e74ec3884
+ 667819b617c88bd886dc2001f612b5c7a4d396c3
+ fd41328a84b0a127affa6fe4328c93e933de378c
+ cfe1807e5d4acc6b5e75f4463dadb3b1c957376f
```

This is a good thing.

I now want to execute this command from within a bash script and capture the output into an array using the following code:

```
commit_hashes=(`git cherry origin/Dev`)
echo ${commit_hashes[@]}
```

which yields the following output:

```
+ 95b117c39869a810595f1e169c64e728d2d7443d + e126f1b996ecf1d2a8cf744c74daa92cce338123 + 869169a6cb0bbe8f1922838798580a1e74ec3884 + 667819b617c88bd886dc2001f612b5c7a4d396c3 + fd41328a84b0a127affa6fe432
8c93e933de378c + cfe1807e5d4acc6b5e75f4463dadb3b1c957376f
```

This is not a good thing

**My list of commits is being returned as a string which I must first break up before I can use it. After some searching I found out that if I add `IFS=""` to my script before the capturing of the data, my problems would be solved.**

So I edited my code to read

```
IFS=""
commit_hashes=(`git cherry origin/Dev`)
echo ${commit_hashes[@]}
```

which output

```
+ 95b117c39869a810595f1e169c64e728d2d7443d
+ e126f1b996ecf1d2a8cf744c74daa92cce338123
+ 869169a6cb0bbe8f1922838798580a1e74ec3884
+ 667819b617c88bd886dc2001f612b5c7a4d396c3
+ fd41328a84b0a127affa6fe4328c93e933de378c
+ cfe1807e5d4acc6b5e75f4463dadb3b1c957376f
```

This completely ended my sense of reality.

I like to know why things are doing what they're doing, so after some more searching I found out that this is called the `Internal Field Separator` and it is used on Unix systems by command interpretors to figure where to break patterns up into tokens.

This I understand.

What I don't understand is

1. Why setting this variable to an empty string allowed it to handle my array data in a sane manner.
2. Why I had to set it so in the first place, instead of the interpretor realising it was dealing with array data and handling it appropriately.
3. What effect setting the Internal Field Separator to an empty string will have in the grand scheme of things, since by default it contains the characters for a space, a tab and a newline.

Some help in getting my head around these three points would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [man bash/Arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays). Everything is fine with your array. When you do

```
echo ${commit_hashes[@]}
```

echo shows all array elements on one line, as it is told to. When you say

```
for i in `seq 10`; do
    echo ${commit_hashes[$i]}
done
```

you will see that just one entry per line is shown.

When you set `IFS=` to an empty string however, the result of `git cherry` isn't broken up into multiple values. The whole string including the newlines is assigned to the first array element. If you

```
echo ${commit_hashes[0]}
```

in your second case, you will see, that echo shows all output lines.